# Struggle with async.parallel

Tags: javascript, express, asynchronous, ejs

I'm trying to stack up a few mongodb results before I ship it all off to ejs. I don't think I've quite mastered the art of async.parallel though ... Any pointers would be appreciated!

Maybe it would be better to investigate async/await a little further for this script?

I'm kind of new at this - as you understand - and I'm not quite sure that my route is good ...

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const async = require('async');
const format = require('date-fns/format');
const norskDato = require('date-fns/locale/nb');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// ------------------ START MONGODB-CONNECTION -------------------------------
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var db; 

MongoClient.connect(mongo_connection, (err, client) => {
    console.log('MongoClient.connect');
    if(err) { return console.log(err); }
    db = client.db(database);
    // Express serverstart
    app.listen(port, function() {
        console.log("Jonas sin Express-server!");
    });
    });

// Define today start and end
var start = new Date();
start.setHours(0,0,0,0);
var slutt = new Date();
slutt.setHours(23,59,59,999);

// Stack up results from mongodb queries
var stack = {};

// First query
stack.scandic_enk_std = function(callback){
    var query = {skaptdato: {$gte: start, $lt: slutt}, personer: 1, romtype: {$ne: "Non-refundable"} };
    var order = { romnavn: 1, fradato: 1};
    app.get('/revMan/query', (req, res) => { 
        db.collection('scandic_priser').find(query).sort(order).toArray((err, result) => {
        if (err) return console.log(err)        
        callback(err, result);
        });
    });
};

// second query
// ... will be made when the first one actually works

// Render to ejs
async.parallel(stack, function(err, result) {
    //console.log("Stack:" + stack);  || This logs the stack and it looks good
    console.log(result); // logs the result and it looks great
    app.get(mappe, (req, res) => {  
        res.render('index', result ); // index.ejs is dead/empty
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey, could you provide a MVCE instead of your full code?  If you want to understand and not just get the answer, you will probably get better quality answers that explain the issue and not just haw to fix this code.

Comment: Also, what is it exactly that you're having trouble understanding.  It sounds like you're having issues with ejs, not async.parallel.

Comment: That's a fair point @c1moore. I'll try to find some time to rewrite. Since I'm new at JS, Node, express, MongoDB and ejs  - it's sometimes difficult for me to see where my problem begins - that's why I provided the full code. To be honest; I now suspect my issue here is my (lacking) understanding of express ...?

Comment: And for the record: I'd much rather have a principal explenation to my problem than a fixed code. After all - I'm in here to learn :-)